# Как сравнивать строки в Shell?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, unix, shell

Разрабатываю программу на языке shell, которая отслеживает изменения прав доступа в поддереве указанного каталога.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Интервал (в сек.) между проверками
TIME_INT=5

DIR="$*";
#Прежние права
RIGHTS="";
#Новые права
NEWRIGHTS="";

[ -z "$DIR" ] && { echo -e "Не указана директория.\nИспользование: $0 <dir>"; exit 1; }
[ -d "$DIR" ] || { echo "Директория: $DIR не найдена."; exit 1; }

#while true; do
#find "$DIR" -exec stat -c '%A %n' {} \;
NEWRIGHTS=$(find "$DIR" -exec stat -c '%A %n' {} \;)
RIGHTS="$NEWRIGHTS l"
#Если проверка уже была
if [ ! -z "$RIGHTS" ]
then
    #Если предыдущие права совпадают с новыми...
    if [ "$RIGHTS" == "$NEWRIGHTS" ]
    then
        echo "Права доступа не изменились"
    else
        #Перебираем подкаталоги и выводим изменившиеся
        old=()
        new=()
        while read -r line; do
            old+=("$line")
        done <<< "$RIGHTS"
        while read -r line; do
            new+=("$line")
        done <<< "$NEWRIGHTS"
        #Сравниваем предыдущие права с новыми
        i=0
        while (( $i < ${#old[@]} ))
        do
            if [ "${old[$i]}" != "${new[$i]}" ]
            then
                echo "Changes: ${old[$i]} =>  ${new[$i]}"
                i=$(( i+1 ))
            else
                echo ""
            fi
        done
    fi
else
    RIGHTS=$NEWRIGHTS
fi
RIGHTS=$NEWRIGHTS
#sleep $TIME_INT
#echo "$RIGHTS";
#done
```

Ошибка возникает при переборе массива и сравнении его элементов:

```
if [ "${old[$i]}" != "${new[$i]}" ]
```

Перерыл весь интернет, перепробовал и "равно ли", и "не равно ли":

```
if [ "${old[$i]}" = "${new[$i]}" ]
if [ "${old[$i]}"="${new[$i]}" ]
if [ ${old[$i]} != ${new[$i]} ]
if (( "${old[$i]}" == "${new[$i]}" ))
```

Каждый раз при вызове программы зависает консоль или пишет, что это операторы для сравнения арифметических чисел.

Примечательно, что сравнение строковых переменных перед этим работает ([ "$RIGHTS" == "$NEWRIGHTS" ]), но когда доходит до элементов массива...

Прошу помочь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно использовать `=` для равенства и `!=` для неравенства:

```
if [ "${old[$i]}" = "${new[$i]}" ]
```

А зависает у вас потому, что в `else` вы не делаете `i=$(( i+1 ))` и продолжаете в бесконечном цикле сравнивать элементы по одному и тому же индексу.

Comment: При if [ "${old[$i]}" != "${new[$i]}" ] все равно не работает

Comment: А бесконечный цикл вы исправили?

Comment: Все-таки ошибка была из-за бесконечного цикла. Спасибо.